# What is the equivalent of Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS for poco libraries?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, poco

For building my C++ project statically with `Boost`, I can use the following `cmake` command:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
```

Is there a same function for POCO libraries?

Answer (score 0):

`Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` is an option of the boost find module. This is a file which contains informations for cmake on where to find all of the boost components (headers and libs, but not only). When you call `find_package` cmake search for this file, and based on the options you set perform a couple more operation, as for the example storing the names of the dynamic libraries or the static ones for linking.

I suppose you are searching POCO components in the same way you search for boost, so maybe POCO has the same informations. In this case I suggest you to check the `<somenamerelatedtoPOCO>.cmake` file.